# AS3 call to a possibly undefined method through a refernce with a static type?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have been away from actionscript for a long time and not 100% why this is happening, I will simplify the class below:

```
package{

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class OpiaRobot extends MovieClip{

        public function OpiaRobot(){ }

        public function botAction(e:MouseEvent):void{ }

        public function run(e:Event):void{

            this.botaction();

        }

    }

var opiaBot:OpiaRobot = new OpiaRobot();
```

The call to botaction causes:

call to a possibly undefined method through a refernce with a static type?

Why as it should be an instance? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that is your exact code, it's probably because you try to use `botaction()` when you should use `botAction(MouseEvent)`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, however it also made me notice the function should be botAction not botaction which was the main issue. That said the new problem is now as it is expecting a mouse event, putting botAction(MouseEvent) leads to coercion of class. So what should be the correct argument if it is not being called by an event?

Comment: Thanks for making me notice the error, I did not think it was possible to call and event null but public function botAction(e:MouseEvent=null):void{ } did the trick.